# How to get a subtag value on a d3 selection result when using each

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code for determining if an element ended up on the same x-axis as another node...

```
function dragended(d, i) {
  var selection = svg.selectAll("g")
  console.log("Drag Ended "+selection.size())
  selection.each(function(s){
    if(d != s && (d.x > (s.x-15) && d.x < (s.x+15))){
      // In here I need to figure out the text
    }
  });
}
```

The rendered svg looks like this...

```
<g>
   <circle r="30" stroke="black" fill="blue" cx="312.95009190616844" cy="255.4427197617464"></circle>
   <text text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10px" dx="312.95009190616844" dy="255.4427197617464">FAA</text>
</g>
```

So basically I want FAA, how would I get this information?

Comment: `d3.select(this).select("text").text()` -- I'm sure you could have figured that out yourself.

Comment: Guess you just don't know how slow I am :-), I was pretty close in my defense.